# Inverting column data through a Query

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

In order to create a specific chart, I need to look for the values of column `H` in reverse to which they are presented. I tried via Query:

```
=QUERY(H2:J, "select H order by J desc", 0)
```

But it returned in the wrong way as you can see:

[image]

I would like to know what would need to be adjusted. Because did not return in the exact inverse sequence of column `H` as it should in theory happen.

Link to Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ehtyuyiAiuQvQUWgMrYBreUMA94jnAliu-VcHfBFi5s/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({ROW(H2:H), H2:H}, 
 "select Col2 
  where Col2 is not null 
  order by Col1 desc", 0))
```

[image: 0]